# Как стилизовать элемент счетчика?

Tags: html, css, счетчики, изображения

```
<li><span class="days">24</span></li>
```

Как можно получить такой элемент как на картинке [image: картинка] с помощью `css` (белая полоска зачеркивания идет перед цифрой)?

P.S.: цифры при этом меняются динамически

Comment: @lexxl цифры черные, зачеркивание белое - я надеюсь вы обратили на это внимание

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
span {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ffd800;
    font: 20px/1 Arial;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

span:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<span class="days">24</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
span.days {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  padding: 7px 0;
  background: #FCDB00;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
span.days:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 36px;
  height: 1px;
  content: '';
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li><span class="days">24</span></li>
</ul>
```